# Can I have a CNAME and TXT record for the same subdomain?

Tags: heroku, dns, google-search-console

I have a Heroku app on a custom domain, as described in their [Dev Center article about custom domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

For Google Webmaster Tools, I'd like to verify ownership using the [DNS method](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176792) with a TXT record.

Naturally, these two records would be for the same subdomain.

Can I do this? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, just add a TXT record through your DNS provider.  One way to verify is via dig:

```
$ dig foo.com TXT
...
foo.com.    1800    IN  TXT "google-site-verification=XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```